# Stochastic Control with Stochastic Cost-functional

Tags: stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Is there any literature dealing with a stochastic control problem whose cost-functional $J_t$ is stochastic also?

That is, let $X_t^u$ is the solution to a controlled SDE
$$
dX_t = \mu(t,u_t,X_t^u)dt + \sigma(t,u_t,X_t^u)dW_t
,
$$ $Y_t$ is a continuous stochastic process of $W_t$ and $J_t$ is the $\mathfrak{F}_t$-predictable loss functional
$$
J_t(u_t)\triangleq \mathbb{E}\left[
\int_0^t \left(
u_sX_s^u-Y_s
\right)^2
ds
\mid
\mathfrak{F}_t^{X}
\right].  
$$
How can we solve for the optimal control $u_t^{\star}$ since $J_t$ is only measurable wrt $X$'s filtration and not $Y$'s?